# Getting cloud.google.com/go/datastore gives malformed record data for golang.org/x/lint

Tags: go

I have a Go module where I am trying to integrate with Google Cloud store. I am using Go v1.14. When I do go get on the cloud datastore, it gives the following error.

```
go: cloud.google.com/go/datastore upgrade => v1.1.0
go get: cloud.google.com/go/datastore@v1.1.0 requires
    google.golang.org/api@v0.17.0 requires
    cloud.google.com/go@v0.38.0 requires
    golang.org/x/lint@v0.0.0-20190301231843-5614ed5bae6f/go.mod: verifying module: golang.org/x/lint@v0.0.0-20190301231843-5614ed5bae6f/go.mod: malformed record data
```

Below are the contents of my go.mod file

```
module <MyNamespace>.com/<moduleName>

go 1.14

require (
    github.com/stretchr/testify v1.5.1
)
```

I don’t really understand the error. How can I understand it?

Answer (score 3):

After struggling for a few hours I discovered that trying the same after clearing local cache worked. I am not getting this exception any more.

Comment: To clean the go mod cache use:
`go ​clean -modcache`